# How to add ionic devApp support in a cordova plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-plugins, ionic-devapp

I have a cordova plugin which supports Android, iOS and browser platforms. But when adding the plugin in an ionic app that is being developed/built using `ionic serve` or ionic devApp, the error comes as 'plugin is not defined'. Is there a way to add the ionic devApp support to a cordova plugin ? If it means only using the browser code for all the platforms(Not using any native platform code), then it works for me. Thanks in advance.

I have added the browser platform to my plugin but it does not work with `ionic serve` even when the app is running on browser. Note that the plugin works fine on browser when the app is run using `ionic cordova run browser` command.

I want the cordova plugin to be compatible with all platforms - Android, iOS , browser and devApp. My expectation are that when the app is run using `ionic cordova run android/ios/browser` command, it should use the native code of my cordova plugin. And when the app is run using `ionic serve` or `ionic devApp`, then it should use the web code.